# virt-convert OVF to KVM

Tags: virtualization, redhat, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, ovf

I use a Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization system and need to get a VM off the system an onto a standalone box running KVM.  Red Hat don't seem to support a way to do this, but commented that the latest virt-convert should do it.

I tried copying the image off the nfs export domain (both ovf definition and disk file), then ran

```
virt-convert -i ovf -o virt-image ovf-file.ovf
```

But I get the error: list index out of range

The problem seems the same as [this](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhelv6-beta-list/2010-October/msg00032.html).  I've tried it on RHEL 6, Centos 5.6 and Fedora 14.  Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the disk image from the export domain, why not simply create a new VM in virt-manager or virsh, with the same params the RHEV one had, and attach the disk image to it?